# How to integrate Chicago Boss and Webmachine ?

Tags: erlang, webmachine, chicagoboss

I just want to develop a RESTful api server with webmachine, but i want to use chicago boss's tools in the same time , Does anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

For now there is no way to do that, Actually it is on my todo list as the maintainer of CB, that you should be able to create a module as a Webmachine resource and just tell it what module to use and some other options and have it work, but I haven't written it yet